# App developed by ionic3 move downward about the height of statusbar on ios 11

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run the app on ios 11, I found that the fixed-content(or ion-content) and fixed-scroll(or ion-scroll)move downward about the height of phone's statusbar.

I had found some solutions by search, but they are all with Object-c.

The solutions say reason is IOS11 has canceled `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property.

I know nothing about Object-c，and changing files builded by ionic is not good.

Can I fix this bug by update some modules or by set some options by javascript?
[image]

Comment: Looks like an issue, report it on https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues. But make sure you have read this first https://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

After I updated to ios 11.2.1，the bug disappeared.